# Lettuce redis client command retry mechanism

Tags: redis, lettuce, keydb

Is there any mechanism in the lettuce client to retry the command if it doesn't receive a response in some time?
I have observed that lettuce is retrying the command after 200 ms if the response is not received.

Can someone help with the conceptual understanding of this ?

Is it something related to https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Command-execution-reliability ?

how lettuce and redis ensure that connection is established? what is the mechanism ?